# INPC Как реализовать выполнение дополнительного метода и вывести результат

Tags: c#, uwp

Доброго времени суток!
Такая ситуация.Изучаю С# и пишу приложение под `UWP`. Приложение работает с `API` `Vk` и выполняет некоторые несложные действия по получению списков друзей, информации о пользователе и тд. Столкнулась с тем, что получение постов пользователя и комментариев - разные методы. Но, чтобы получить комментарии, нужен айди поста. Сами посты вывожу используя `INotifyPropertyChanged` из листа, в который записываю данные после получения и десериальзации `json`. 
В чем собственно вопрос. При клике на элемент выведенного списка мне, выходит, нужно вызывать метод, который возьмет айди данного элемента, отправит запрос и получит список комментов. И этот список потом нужно будет вывести. И так повторять и для последующих элементов исходного списка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализуется? Информации по `INPC` много, а я даже не могу понять как правильно сформировать поисковый запрос для данного случая.

На данный момент выводила только сам лист и по клику ту информацию, которую получила данным методом. Там возвращает только общее количество комментов и лайков. Вот мой код. Он весьма быдловат, но я только учусь,не судите строго.

```
public class PostView : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class Photo
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int album_id { get; set; }
            public int owner_id { get; set; }
            public int user_id { get; set; }
            public string photo_75 { get; set; }
            public string photo_130 { get; set; }
            public string photo_604 { get; set; }
            public string photo_807 { get; set; }
            public string photo_1280 { get; set; }
            public int width { get; set; }
            public int height { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public int date { get; set; }
            public string access_key { get; set; }
        }

        public class Attachment
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
            public Photo photo { get; set; }
        }

        public class PostSource
        {
            public string type { get; set; }
        }

        public class Comments
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public int can_post { get; set; }
        }

        public class Likes
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public int user_likes { get; set; }
            public int can_like { get; set; }
            public int can_publish { get; set; }
        }

        public class Reposts
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public int user_reposted { get; set; }
        }

        public class Views
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
        }

        public class Item
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public int from_id { get; set; }
            public int owner_id { get; set; }
            public int date {get; set ; }
            public int marked_as_ads { get; set; }
            public string post_type { get; set; }
            public string text { get; set; }
            public int can_pin { get; set; }
            public List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
            public PostSource post_source { get; set; }
            public Comments comments { get; set; }
            public Likes likes { get; set; }
            public Reposts reposts { get; set; }
            public Views views { get; set; }
        }

        public class Group
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string screen_name { get; set; }
            public int is_closed { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public int is_admin { get; set; }
            public int is_member { get; set; }
            public string photo_50 { get; set; }
            public string photo_100 { get; set; }
            public string photo_200 { get; set; }
        }

        public class Response
        {
            public int count { get; set; }
            public List<Item> items { get; set; }
            public List<object> profiles { get; set; }
            public List<Group> groups { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public Response response { get; set; }
        }

        public string token_;
        public string usId_;
        // public RootObject objPost;
        List<Item> wallPostsGet { get; set; }



        private List<Item> wallList;
        public List<Item> WallList
        {
            get { return wallList; }
            set { wallList = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }


        private Item wallChoise;

        public Item WallChoise
        {
            get { return wallChoise; }
            set { wallChoise = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }






    public PostView()
        {
            _GetPosts();


        }

        public async void _GetPosts()
        {
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder =
                        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile T =
                await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("token.txt");
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile UId =
                await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("idCurrentUser.txt");

                usId_ = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(UId);

            token_ = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(T);


            string url1 = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=" + usId_;
            string url2 = "&count=100&filter=all&extended=1&fields=first_name,last_name&access_token=" + token_;
            string url3 = "&v=5.64";
            var url = url1 + url2 + url3;
           var json1 = await FetchAsync(url);

            var Result1 = json1.Substring(12, json1.Length - 13);
            Debug.WriteLine(Result1);

            var objPost = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(Result1);
           WallList = objPost.items;


        }

        public async Task<string> FetchAsync(string url)
        {
            string jsonString;

            using (var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
            {
                var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(url);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return jsonString;
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }




}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо пройтись по списку и для каждого айдишника поста запросить каменты?
Это можно сделать с помощью оператора foreach.

```
foreach (var item in WallList)
{
    тут отправляете запрос на каждый элемент, используя item.id
}
```

Не совсем понятно причем тут INPC.